# FFT library for C++ or tutorial

Tags: library, c++, math

I have a problem with found good FFT library, for simple use.

I have 2D array which need passed via FFT.

I'm looking for FFT library.

I have 2D array of ints (info about pixels in images) and I need pass FFT on this Array and save.

You have some library for advice?

Someone who take me some advice/tutorial how use this library?

[Library FFT](http://www.fftw.org/)

.. or FT

Thaks

Answer (score 1):

The library of choice for any FFT task is

## [FFTW](http://fftw.org/)

It has C and Fortran interfaces and is therefore be usable in C++ as well.

Answer (score 1):

[PocketFFT](https://github.com/mreineck/pocketfft) is a really good alternative to FFTW. It has a permissive open-source license (rather than the viral license of FFTW), a simpler API, and comparable performance*.

There is a C version and a C++ version, the latter is newer. It is based on the FFTPack implementation (which was written in Fortran).

---

<sup>* At least in my testing on an M1 Mac, maybe FFTW is better tuned for Intel processors?.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (a free Matlab implementation) has a builtin function [`fft2()`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Signal-Processing.html#index-fft2) which calls FFTW 3.

```
: fft (x)
: fft (x, n)
: fft (x, n, dim)
Compute the discrete Fourier transform of x 
using a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithm.
```

So I think, if you can call `fft2()` in Octave you have FFTW Version 3 installed.